# Creating 'Non Visual' .NET User Controls

Tags: c#, .net, components

How do I create non **visual components** in .NET that can be dragged and dropped onto a Form ?

For example the imagelist component is a non visual component, it appears in the toolbox and can be dragged onto a form and properties can be set for that component.

How can I achieve that ? How can I create **non visual** components. I know about user controls but that is not what I am looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By deriving from [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) instead of [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx).

```
public class MyNonVisualControl: Component
{

}
```

Comment: Yea, refer to the MSDN reference on ImageList, and you'll get the idea http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28VS.71%29.aspx